# Linked List Insertion problems

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to insert an object (bird) that holds a name and an ID number
I'm having problems inserting the object into my linked list

```
bool List342::Insert(Bird *obj)
{
    Node *insNode = new Node;
    insNode->data = obj;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = insNode;
        return true;
    }

    //cout << head->data->getID();
    if ((insNode->data->getID()) <= (head->data->getID()))
    {
        insNode->next = head;
        head = insNode;
        return true;
    }

    Node *pNode = head;
    while ((pNode->next != NULL) && ((pNode->next)->data->getID() <= insNode->data->getID()))
    {
        pNode = pNode->next;
    }
    insNode->next = pNode->next;
    pNode->next = insNode;
    return true;
}
```

It doesn't seem to insert correctly
I tried putting a cout code to see what numbers are being compared
for example
cout << head->data->getID()
and it seems to output the current id of the current bird
and not the id of the head (should be the lowest ID)

please and thank you!

Comment: 1) Are you sure `next` is initialized to NULL? If it isn't you should  do `insNode->next = head;` or `insNode->next = NULL;` when inserting to an empty list. 2) The logic seems a bit inconsistent: when the new item is equal to the first one, you insert it in the front of the list, but when it's equal to some other data, you skip them and insert at the end of a group.

Comment: Your function always returns true, to me that is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see where the function would return `false`. So I think there is no any sense to declare the function as having return type `bool` because it always returns `true`.

I have declared the functtion as having return type `void` though you may declare the function as having return type `bool` as before but in this case you need to add last statement that will return `true`.
Maybe it would be better to declare the function as returning a reference to the list itself.

The function could be defined the following way

```
void List342::Insert( Bird *bird )
{
    Node *prev = NULL;
    Node *current = head;

    while ( current != NULL && !( bird->getID() < current->data->getID() ) )
    { 
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    Node *newnode = new Node { bird, current };

    if ( prev != NULL ) prev->next = newnode;
    else head = newnode;
}
```

I suppose that Node has the following definition

```
struct Node
{
    Bird *data;
    Node *next;
};
```

You may substitute statement

```
Node *newnode = new Node { bird, current };
```

for

```
Node *newnode = new Node;
newnode->data = bird;
newnode->next = current;
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is working fine for me.
I hope, the head is change outside of the insert function.
Shall you check the calling portion of the insert or any other places modifying the head value.